# How We Can get the async Method Name In c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to get the name of this method by using **Reflection** etc...I use a lot of stuff but I 'm tired please help me.
If the function is sync then it below code will work fine. Please go through the below code, that will clear you my question.

```
// this will work fine
public void Test()
{
// This GetCurrentMethod() will you the name of current method
string CurrentMethodName = GetCurrentMethod();
// output will be CurrentMethodName = Test
}


// this will not work
      public async Task<int> GETNumber(long ID)
      {
// This GetCurrentMethod() will you the name of current method if the method is sync or not async
string CurrentMethodName = GetCurrentMethod();
           return await Task.Run(() => { return 20; });
      }
```

This method provide me Name of non async method. but how I get above method  name

```
>     [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
>           public static string GetCurrentMethod()
>           {
>                 var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
>                 StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(1);
>                 return stackFrame.GetMethod().Name;
>           }
```

But this method is working only for not async method. So how get current async method name in c#

Comment: The problem here is that the "stack" in your specific case, using `Task.Run` isn't a natural stack as such, a threadpool thread has been spun up to run your anonymous method, as such, the stack doesn't contain anything specific to the `GETNumber` method. *However*, in this particular case, the generated name for your anonymous method contains the name, the name of the method will be something like `.<GETNumber>b__1_0`.

Comment: Now, the question is, what exactly do you need the name for?

Comment: Check: [Get current method name from async function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20158902/1351076)

Comment: The duplicate is only valid for your specific case, however, which involves an anonymous method or a lambda expression. If your async method is a normal method, this won't work. Are you sure `nameof(GETNumber)` isn't going to do the trick?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is not really possible. The compiler creates a *state machine* for the `async` method, something like that

```
public class GetNumberStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    // ....
    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        // here your actual code happens in steps between the 
        // await calls
    }
}
```

And converts your method into something like that:

```
public async Task<int> GetNumber()
{
     GetNumberStateMachin stateMachine = new GetNumberStatemachine();
     stateMachine.\u003C\u003Et__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();
     stateMachine.\u003C\u003E1__state = -1;
     stateMachine.\u003C\u003Et__builder.Start<GetNumberStatemachine>(ref stateMachine);
     return stateMachine.\u003C\u003Et__builder.Task;
}
```

So what calls your `GetCurrentMethod()` at runtime is no longer your `GetNumber()`.

---

But you can get the name of the calling method via the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string GetCurrentMethod([CallingMemberName] string method = "")
{
     return method;
}

public async Task<int> GetNumber(long ID)
{
   int result = await Task.Run(() => { return 20; });
   Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentMethod()); // prints GetNumber
   return result;
}
```

This even works with `async` methods (I'm not sure, but I guess the argument is replaced at compile time).

Comment: Side note - same is true for iterator methods which are yielding results. Though is it possible to still get name of method which contains state machine?