# How to get the method name that originated the exception in OnExceptionAsync c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get the method name and the class name where from exception is originated in my exception filter but unable to do so. I think because of the async methods used. I am getting MoveNext as the method instead of the actual method name.

Please find below the code

```
 public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Exception filter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            
            var s = new StackTrace(context.Exception);
            var methodname=s.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;


            Logger.LogError(context.Exception, context.Exception.Message);
            
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, res);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

      }
```

I searched a lot but couln't find any answer.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: you can try `new StackTrace(context.Exception).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name`

Comment: Hi @viveknuna this is giving MoveNext

Comment: `GetFrame(0)` also not working?

Comment: what about this `var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();                
var methodname = s.GetFrames().Select(f => f.GetMethod()).First(m => m.Module.Assembly == name).Name;`

Comment: @viveknuna actually i tried GetFrame(0) but put wrong in the question by mistake as I was trying different things

Comment: @viveknuna, Still the same, I think all these things will work in case the functions are non-async.

Comment: yes you are right , I didn't notice the `async`

Comment: @viveknuna ,Is there any way to get that in asynchronous functions also as almost all my functions are async. And I have different layers and exception can happen any where. i needed to log this info in the db .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to get it.I am providing the answer so that it can help someone with similar situation.

I found the answer from this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158902/get-current-method-name-from-async-function/25813133)

Please find the code below

```
 public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Exception filter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            
            Logger.LogError(context.Exception, context.Exception.Message);

            var s = new StackTrace(context.Exception);
            var r = s.GetFrame(0);
            UtilityDAL.WriteExceptionLog("None", context.Exception, GetMethodName(r.GetMethod()), GetClassName(r.GetMethod()));

            context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, res);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private string GetMethodName(System.Reflection.MethodBase method)
        {
            string _methodName = method.DeclaringType.FullName;

            if (_methodName.Contains(">") || _methodName.Contains("<"))
            {
                _methodName = _methodName.Split('<', '>')[1];
            }
            else
            {
                _methodName = method.Name;
            }

            return _methodName;
        }

        private string GetClassName(System.Reflection.MethodBase method)
        {
            string className = method.DeclaringType.FullName;

            if (className.Contains(">") || className.Contains("<"))
            {
                className = className.Split('+')[0];
            }
            return className;
        }
    }
```

It works fine for both async and non async functions.

Note: I am not sure if this will work fine for all the cases but till now it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension like this and get the details in the case of `async` method.

```
public static class SampleExtension
{
    public static string GetOriginMethod(this MethodBase methodBase, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
    {
        return memberName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives the current method name "OnExceptionAsync" no the method name wherefrom the exception originated.